# Getting Query String parameters in struts2 Action

Tags: struts2

I have came across an issue where i am unable to find a solution.I am working on a web-application and have to impliment `Oauth`, things are working fine for me except one issue,in my redirect back URL from `Yahoo` i am getting several parametersand i need to access few of them in my action class.

Now i can easily create a property in my action class with its getter and setter methods but the name of the property is

```
openid.response_nonce
```

and my Eclipse editor will not allow me to name a variable like this.Though one solution is add `RequestAware` interceptor in my action class and access the parameter.

my Question is can i access it without using `RequestAware` inteceptor?

Comment: i know about that,but my issue is with the name of parameter `openid.response_nonce` which i am getting back from Yahoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a RequestAware interceptor... There is a Servlet-Config interceptor which will check if your action has one of the following interfaces: ServletContextAware, ServletRequestAware, ServletResponseAware, ParameterAware, RequestAware, SessionAware, ApplicationAware, PrincipalAware.

The Servlet-Config interceptor is part of the default-stack, which you are probably already using. So there is no additional cost or configuration required to use one of the aware interfaces.

That aside, if you have a parameter called "openid.response_nonce" which contains a string, you should be able to refer to it with:

```
//following not tested, and not checked for syntax errors

private Map openid = new HashMap();
//In Constructor{
  oauth.put("response_nonce","");
}
//create BOTH a getter and setter for openid
public getOpenid(){
  return openid;
}

public setOpenid(Map openid){
  this.openid = openid;
}
```

Now struts2 should be able to figure out how to set the value... I think, sorry didn't test it.  You could always create a class called Openid with a response_nonce property(along with the appropriate getters and setters for that Class)... but I think in this case it might be best to just use RequestAware if you only need that single property.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you maybe looking for the Alias interceptor. http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/alias-interceptor.html

Regards